# Why is corn kitnius?

Tags: halacha, sources-mekorot, minhag, passover, kitniyos-semigrain-legume

The reason why potatoes isn't kitnius is because it wasn't out there when they made the kitniyut rule, but did they have corn on that time so it should be kitnius?

Comment: "The reason why potatoes isn't kitnius is because it wasn't out there when they made the kitniyut rule" How do you know this?

Comment: Rabbi Moshe Feinstein, Iggrot Moshe, Orech Chaim 3:63.

Comment: Welcome to MiYodeya Avrohom. Since MY is different from other sites you might be used to, see [here](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/a/3887/11501) for a guide which might help understand the site. You should edit the Igrot Moshe reference into your question, comments are temporary and often get deleted. Hope to see you around!

Comment: I heard in Yeshivah that when some Rabbis like the Chayey Adam suggested banning the potato for Pesach as well, the majority said that it would be taking away something that has become a staple. It wouldn't be right to take away such a basic food from people who need it to survive on Pesach.

Comment: I have heard it said that the reason "corn" (i.e. the new world crop maize) was considered forbidden on Pesach is because of confusion with "korn" (i.e. the Yiddish word for "rye").  In other words, "Can you eat corn bread on Pesach?" gets the answer "Of course you can't eat *kornbroyt* on Pesach!" According to this theory, the "corn is kitniyot" ruling came retroactively, to explain the established custom of not eating maize, which was based on a translation error. But I don't know if this is just folklore or if there is a source for it.

Answer (score 0):

From [OU kosher](https://oukosher.org/passover/articles/what-is-kitniyot/):

> Iggeros Moshe explains that the minhag to not eat kitniyot developed differently than other minhagim and therefore rules that only foods which we know were specifically included in the minhag are forbidden. [See also Chok Yaakov 453:9 who makes a similar point].
>
> With this he explains the generally accepted custom to not consider potatoes to be kitniyot even though logically they should be, as follows: the minhag of kitniyot can be dated back at least until [Maharil](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yaakov_ben_Moshe_Levi_Moelin), who died in 1427, and potatoes didn’t come to Europe until the 16th century, so potatoes were a “new” vegetable which wasn’t included in the minhag.
>
> **An important “exception” to the aforementioned rule that “new” vegetables aren’t included in the minhag, is corn/maize which [Mishnah Berurah 453:4](https://www.sefaria.org/Mishnah_Berurah.453.4?with=all&lang=bi) and others rule is kitniyot even though it was introduced to Europe after the minhag had already begun.**

More info on kitniyot can be found [at the link above](https://oukosher.org/passover/articles/what-is-kitniyot/).

Comment: I don't see how this answers the question. It just restates the premeses of the question: potatoes are not prohibited but corn is.